# Partial file input

Tags: input, external-files

Is there a way to input a part of a LaTeX `file1.tex` specified by say some markers into another LaTeX file `file2.tex`? (For example, I don't want to input `\begin{document}`, `\maketitle`, etc.)

I know that I could create `file3.tex` with the input stuff for `file1.tex` and `file2.tex`, but being able to do it directly (as above) would be much more convenient.

Here's an example of `file1.tex` with what I want to include in `file2.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\title{My Tikz Pictures}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

% Start input here

\newcommand{\picA}{...}
\newcommand{\picZ}{...}

% End input here

\begin{document} 
....
\end{document}
```

Comment: Depends if you want to input the file _up to_ a given point, or from that point _onwards_, but it should be simple either way.  Can you please clarify (maybe with an example skeleton of the files)

Comment: I would like to have a start and end point for the input block, as in the updated outline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you want to include are common definitions for a project of yours, I recommend you make a package file, say, `adampics.sty`:

```latex
% Next line is optional
\ProvidesPackage{adampics}[2020-10-10 v1.0 Common definitions for Adam's documents]
\newcommand{\picA}{...}
\newcommand{\picZ}{...}
```

then just do `\usepackage{adampics}` in your documents.

---

If, for some reason, you *do* need to read in the complete file and extract a part of it, then you can do something like this.  In the file to be input, add two anchors `\csname adamSTARTinput\endcsname` and `\csname adamSTOPinput\endcsname`:

```latex
% loadedfile.tex
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\title{My Tikz Pictures}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\csname adamSTARTinput\endcsname

\newcommand{\picA}{...}
\newcommand{\picZ}{...}

\csname adamSTOPinput\endcsname

\begin{document} 
....
\end{document}
```

being a `\csname ...\endcsname`-generated macro, they will do nothing as long as they aren't defined, so running the document above standalone will proceed normally.

Then in the caller document, do:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\inputfilepart#1{%
  \let\adamSTOPinput\endinput
  \long\def\loadfilepartaux##1%
    \csname adamSTARTinput\endcsname{}
  \expandafter\loadfilepartaux\@@input "#1"
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\texttt{\meaning\picZ} % undefined
\inputfilepart{loadedfile.tex}
\texttt{\meaning\picZ} % \long macro:->...

\end{document}
```

(but you have to make sure that the anchors *do* exist in the loaded file, and that the anchors are not within braces).

Comment: That's very smart, Phelype!